# Pick out rows between two dates that have the same time in SQL to Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I would like to import rows from mySQL database into Python.
I would like to take out rows between two dates that have the same timstamp.
I have managed to import between two dates with this line:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp >= %s AND timestamp <=%s", (2020-03-07, 2020-03-10)
```

But I dont know how to spesific only rows where timestamp is for example 10:00:00.
See picture for the database setup.

Database
[image: Database]

Comment: *how to spesific only rows where timestamp is for example 10:00:00* CAST this field to TIME datatype or format it to '%H:%i:%s' (i.e. remove date part), then compare with proper time literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like

```
"""
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE timestamp >= %s 
  AND timestamp <=%s 
  AND DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%H:%i:%s' = %s)
""", ("2020-03-07", "2020-03-10", "10:00:00")
```